# How to address a Gradle sync failure with buttons and a sync issue related to a lock file?

Tags: gradle, synchronization, build.gradle, project

Gradle project sync failed. Buttons: Try Again, Open 'Build' View, Show Log. Sync issue: Couldn't create parent directory for lock file

I tried to solve the given above problem but I can't. Please help me in this regard.